# Read resource files for android on startup before loading MainPage using xamarin

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I want to make an application for android, when i start the application
i want an extern xaml file to set colors for mainpage and other static bindings.

I have done this on an windows app with help of stackowerflow, this is the link to the question
[My Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67947264/is-it-possible-to-have-skins-in-xaml-outside-the-sourcecode-change-xaml-withou)

Can this be done?

Im trying to use the same code with wont fork ofcourse.

I tried to put the file in the asset map, and read with
assetmanager but cant access it in the start session !

Example:

```
                string fileName = Path.Combine(Environment
                .GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), $" 
                {filename}Colors.xaml");

            bool fileexist = File.Exists(fileName);
```

It cant even find my file - i have in the file option:
AndroidAsset
Do not copy

I know it require a long answer - but i have a long question in the linq
and i want the same thing in my android app !

Thanks a million if you can help me.

Comment: [File handling in Xamarin Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/data/files?tabs=windows) OR [File access with Xamarin.Android](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/files/).

Comment: an Android Asset is not a file.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/resources-in-android/android-assets?tabs=windows